# On Change Select is not Triggering Click Event in Safari

Tags: triggers, safari

On Change the Select is not triggering the click event of Input type file in Safari, but it works good in Chrome and Firefox.

Though the input type file is not hidden or visibility none.

My Fiddle :

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/vinoth06/yLshkbwp/8/`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this seems to be the behavior in iOS and Safari.

- The `change` event does get triggered in Safari as well.
- However the **file input click action** alone doesn't get fired.

**Suggestion:**

- If its fine to use a *button* instead of *select*, here's a fiddle extended from yours. https://jsfiddle.net/Le7dcz0b/
- A **button** `click` event works! It's able to open your File upload dialog in Safari/Chrome.